# Как вызвать alert при попытке закрыть вкладку или браузер

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

Привет всем, подскажите как реализовать:
Пытаюсь реализовать скриптик который при закрытии окна или вкладки выведет форму  с предупреждением, что данные могут потеряться.

Логика такая:

Скрипт должен выводить сообщение о том, что данные потеряются, с двумя кнопкам "ок" и "отмена". Срабатывать он должен при закрытии и тогда, когда в адресной строке браузера содержится адрес: [https://имясайта/#/create-incident?from=main](https://%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/#/create-incident?from=main)

во всем остальных случая нет.

Пытался вот так вот сделать:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (  window.onbeforeunload = function() )

    {  
        if (window.location.href == 'https://имясайта/#/create-incident?from=main')
        {
            return "Что-нибудь сообщить пользователю";

        }




    }

</script>
```

Но что-то не работает

Comment: _"но что-то не работает"_ - может, потому, что в представленном коде есть синтаксические ошибки?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/141793/

Comment: добавлю, что при использовании сего для отдельной странице не надо добавлять этот код по всему сайту и проверять урл, а добавить только там где надо.

Comment: в том, то и дело, что весь сайт это одна страница с модальными окнами, котрые подгружаются например /create-uncident и да, если этот обработчик не поддерживается, как мне сообщить пользователю при закрытии окна, что он что-то не доделал?

Comment: Сообщение пользователю выдать не получится, только стандартное "Изменения могут не сохраниться"

Comment: @vp_arth подскажите как сделать ? я просто в тупик зашел )
надо что-бы если строка урл == https://имясайта/#/create-incident?from=main  

выдавалось хоть какое-нибудь сообщение. я просто  уже наверное все перепробовал. а сложного то в этом как мне кажется ничего нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такое кастомизируемое решение:

```js
// Общая функция, перебирает все имеющиеся проверки
var checks = {};
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  for (var i in checks) {
    if (!checks[i]()) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

// Добавляем проверку того, что чекбокс установлен
checks['checkbox_managed'] = function() {
  var ch = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
  return ch.checked;
};
```

```html
<input type=checkbox />Can leave?
<hr />

<a href="//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745461/176064">Leave</a>
```

Аналогично, можете добавить свои проверки:

```
checks['onCreateIncidentPage'] = function() {
  // Возвращаем true, если со страницы можно уйти
  return location.href !== 'https://имясайта/#/create-incident?from=main';
}
```

---

*Вывести произвольный текст в общем случае невозможно.*

Comment: то, что нужно) спасибо